# KDB: set difference

Tags: set, difference, kdb, set-difference

How can one find set (data structure) difference in KDB?
Example:

```
a: 1 2 3 4
b: 2 3
```

expected result: `1 4`. Simple guesses like `a-b` or `a _ b` do not work.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after the keyword [except](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/except/)

```
q)a:1 2 3 4;b:2 3
q)a except b
1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Keyword you are looking for is `except`

`except[b;a],except[a;b]`

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/except/

Edit: fyi 1 except will not cover all differences if b has values not in a:

```
q)b,:10
q)except[a;b]
1 4
q)except[a;b],except[b;a]
1 4 10
```